# branches not executed properly when created in a loop

Tags: groovy, jenkins-workflow

I'm doing proof of concept with Pipeline plugin, and would like to see how to run builds in parallel - and list of builds to be run is highly dynamic, and depends on a specific hardware setup. So, I've tried to create branches dynamically and the run them - no dice! But if I just add them with "hardcoded" indices to a map of branches, everything works ok. I'm a novice in groovy (though I'm pretty good with Java), so it may be a jenkins thing or a groovy thing - I don't really know

```
def branchesFail = [:]
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
    s = i.toString()
    branchesFail [ s ] = { build job: 'nebraska-echo', parameters: [ [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'ARG', value: s ] ] }
}
parallel branchesFail

def branchesPass = [:]

branchesPass [ '0' ] = { build job: 'nebraska-echo', parameters: [ [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'ARG', value: '0' ] ] }
branchesPass [ '1' ] = { build job: 'nebraska-echo', parameters: [ [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'ARG', value: '1' ] ] }
branchesPass [ '2' ] = { build job: 'nebraska-echo', parameters: [ [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'ARG', value: '2' ] ] }
branchesPass [ '3' ] = { build job: 'nebraska-echo', parameters: [ [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'ARG', value: '3' ] ] }
branchesPass [ '4' ] = { build job: 'nebraska-echo', parameters: [ [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'ARG', value: '4' ] ] }

parallel branchesPass
```

The output looks like this:

```
[Pipeline] Execute sub-workflows in parallel : Start
[Pipeline] [0] parallel {: Parallel branch: 0
[Pipeline] [1] parallel {: Parallel branch: 1
[Pipeline] [2] parallel {: Parallel branch: 2
[Pipeline] [3] parallel {: Parallel branch: 3
[Pipeline] [4] parallel {: Parallel branch: 4
[Pipeline] [0] build: Building nebraska-echo
[0] Scheduling project: nebraska-echo
[Pipeline] [1] build: Building nebraska-echo
[1] Scheduling project: nebraska-echo
[Pipeline] [2] build: Building nebraska-echo
[2] Scheduling project: nebraska-echo
[Pipeline] [3] build: Building nebraska-echo
[3] Scheduling project: nebraska-echo
[Pipeline] [4] build: Building nebraska-echo
[4] Scheduling project: nebraska-echo
[0] Starting building: nebraska-echo #58
[Pipeline] } //parallel
[Pipeline] } //parallel
[Pipeline] } //parallel
[Pipeline] } //parallel
[Pipeline] } //parallel
[Pipeline] Execute sub-workflows in parallel : End
[Pipeline] Execute sub-workflows in parallel : Start
[Pipeline] [0] parallel {: Parallel branch: 0
[Pipeline] [1] parallel {: Parallel branch: 1
[Pipeline] [2] parallel {: Parallel branch: 2
[Pipeline] [3] parallel {: Parallel branch: 3
[Pipeline] [4] parallel {: Parallel branch: 4
[Pipeline] [0] build: Building nebraska-echo
[0] Scheduling project: nebraska-echo
[Pipeline] [1] build: Building nebraska-echo
[1] Scheduling project: nebraska-echo
[Pipeline] [2] build: Building nebraska-echo
[2] Scheduling project: nebraska-echo
[Pipeline] [3] build: Building nebraska-echo
[3] Scheduling project: nebraska-echo
[Pipeline] [4] build: Building nebraska-echo
[4] Scheduling project: nebraska-echo

[0] Starting building: nebraska-echo #59
[1] Starting building: nebraska-echo #60
[2] Starting building: nebraska-echo #61
[3] Starting building: nebraska-echo #62
[4] Starting building: nebraska-echo #63
[Pipeline] } //parallel
[Pipeline] } //parallel
[Pipeline] } //parallel
[Pipeline] } //parallel
[Pipeline] } //parallel
[Pipeline] Execute sub-workflows in parallel : End
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

From branches added in a loop only first is executed (no matter number of items in branchesFail), but in branchesPass all jobs are run in parallel, as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Mark.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using a `collectEntries` statement in place of the for loop containing a closure?

```
def branchesFail = (0..4).collectEntries { idx ->
    String sIdx = idx.toString()
    [sIdx, { build job: 'nebraska-echo', parameters: [ [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'ARG', value: sIdx ] ] } ]
}
parallel branchesFail
```

I suspect the issue is the same as the following:

If you create a closure inside a `for` loop, and the closure closes round the iterator variable for the loop, like so:

```
def listOfClosures = []
for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
    listOfClosures << { println i * i }
}
```

Then the closures do not actually get the value until they are executed.  At this point, all of the values of `i` are the same (and in this case, are `5`), so calling:

```
listOfClosures*.call()
```

Will print:

```
25
25
25
25
25
```

I believe you have the same situation above...  Another solution would be to put `def` in  front of `s` so that each closure gets a new shiny copy of `s` to close round

```
def s = i.toString()
```